# Can't select new dynamic jQuery UI .sortable elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having a bit of trouble using jQuery UI .sortable with dynamically created DOM elements.

Basically, I've created a large drag-and-drop form creator / editor and when a new form element is added to the droppable area, it creates a div container (called .connectedsortable), and the form element inside that (called .question).

The outer of the two divs, .connectedsortable is a sortable list, and when there are many of these divs on the page, I can successfully drag a .question from one to the other as they are linked as sortable - so the .question moves and the .connectedsortable doesn't, and if all of the contents of a .connectedsortable are removed, the .connectedsortable is removed from the DOM.

Here lies the issue though.

Because of the UI that I've made, I need to be able to escape the questions from .connectedsortables and move them around the page, and it would suffice if - when the dragging of a .question begins - a new .connectedsortable is created after each existing .createdsortable which the .question can then be placed into.

In my code I have a function that is called on the .sortable start as below (as well as a lot of other code that I've pulled out as it's not necessary for this issue)

```
$('.connectedsortable').sortable({
     connectWith : '.connectedsortable',
     start : function(event, ui) {
         createPlaceholders(ui.item);
     }
}).disableSelection();
```

The function createPlaceholders() then contains the following

```
function createPlaceholders(widget) {

    var placeholder_html = '<div class="connectedsortable"></div>';

    $('.connectedsortable').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.after(placeholder_html);
    });

    $('#innercontent').children('.connectedsortable:first').before(placeholder_html);
    $('.connectedsortable').sortable('refresh');
};
```

This successfully creates a new .connectedsortable after every existing one, BUT I then cannot drop the .question into that container.

I thought that refreshing the sortable at the end of the function would mean that they could then be selected, but that doesn't seem to be the case. This has me truly stumped.

Has anyone come across anything similar in the past? Is there an issue updating the .sortable whilst the .sortable is already doing something, or something along those lines?

Comment: Just a suggestion, making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) might increase your odds of an answer ;)

Comment: I certainly would, but the whole thing is so big I feel that it might so somewhat counter-productive

Comment: In the end, I sussed it.

Painfully, you just have to call the original big .sortable with all it's options again. 

I just extracted it to a function and called that whenever I rebuilt the DOM. Not ideal, but it works.